# How to convert pandas.core.series.Series to string?

Tags: python, pandas

```
Purpose,Date,StockCode,Buy/Sell,Quantity,OrderType,Price,HoldingPeriod
Entry,7-Jul,AAPL,Buy,10,MKT,,
Stop,7-July,AAPL,Sell,10,LMT,100,20
```

Here is my data frame.
I want to covert them into string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many methods for doing this. You'll need to provide more details about your goal to get a more detailed answer.

you can use:

```
.to_string()
```

or

```
.astype(str)
```

or

```
.apply(str)
```

Comment: [pd.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide a reproductible example but you should try:

```
my_series.to_string().replace('\n','')
```